# XtraTreeList - How can I set the value of a CheckEdit cell?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

I am using the DevExpress WinForms XtraTreeList control, and have several columns which contain a Check Box, i.e. I have set the ColumnEdit property of the Columns to a RepositoryCheckEdit.

How can I programatically access the value of a particular CheckEdit cell and set it to True/False?

For text cells, I have used *TreeListNode[index] = "string"* (which is the same as *TreeListNode.SetValue(index, "string")*), but *TreeListNode[index] = boolean* seems to have no effect on the CheckEdit cell.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out neither one of the suggestions worked. Here's what I did to solve the problem.

For the Column cells to display a CheckBox, instead of setting the ColumnEdit property to RepositoryCheckEdit, I set the Column's UnboundType to Boolean, i.e.:

```
TreeListColumn.UnboundType = DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Data.UnboundColumnType.Boolean;
```

Then, in order to set the CheckEdit's value:

```
TreeListNode[index] = true; //false
```

PS - I believe the other methods didn't work 'cause of the RepositoryItemCheckEdit. Apparently, there's some other way to set the CheckEdit value when this is the case (which I have not been able to find).

Thank you for the interest and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index you are referencing is in fact a CheckEdit or RepositoryCheckEdit, cast it as such.

Along these lines:

```
(TreeListNode[index] as CheckEdit).Checked = true;
```

I'd obviously recommend checking if it's null first, before attempting to assign it, but this is just to show you.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help. I don't have the code at my disposal (it's a work project), so I'll only be able to try it out next Tuesday, but I'll definitely let you know how it goes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set Checked property for the whole column look at [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A236.aspx). You have to write a custom iterator which is easy to implement. But bit strange way of doing the iteration.

If you want to set the Checked property only for a perticular TreeListNode item, hope below helps.

```
TreeListNode node;
node.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, but I don't think it quite satisfies my needs. I do not want to set the Checked property for the entire column. In fact, I have a total of 5 CheckEdit columns, and I want to set their checked states for every Node, according to certain data in the database. So I don't want to set the Node itself to Checked. I apologise if the initial question was somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @ Rachel : Still setting the CheckState should satisfy your need. TreeListNode.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
DevExNodes.TreeListNode node = this.treeList1.FindNodeByID(nodeId);
DevExColumns.TreeListColumn column = this.treeList1.Columns.ColumnByName(columnName);
node.SetValue(column, true);
this.treeList1.RefreshCell(node, column);
```

And within the `CustomNodeCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.GetCustomNodeCellEditEventArgs e)` event replace the default cell with a `DevExRepos.RepositoryItemCheckEdit` cell:

```
DevExRepos.RepositoryItemCheckEdit checkEdit = new DevExRepos.RepositoryItemCheckEdit();
checkEdit.ValueChecked = true;
checkEdit.ValueUnchecked = false;
e.RepositoryItem = checkEdit;
```